# What kind of goals would come out of a branding project (from scratch)?

Tags: logo, client-relations, business, branding, identity

I posted this thread several days ago regarding typical goals for a rebrand — [What kind of goals would come out of a rebrand?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91056/what-kind-of-goals-would-come-out-of-a-rebrand)

There were some interesting answers and it got me thinking how different a rebrand is compared to designing an identity from scratch (I hadn't really thought about this when writing the original post).

Am I right in thinking that, when designing an identity from *scratch*, it would be unrealistic for the goal to be based around profits, sales etc?

Should it be something more general? Such as this example?

> We would like a brand identity that appeals to young couples who have recently bought their own homes, we would like something more quirky / offbeat in order to stand out from our competitors in what can sometimes be viewed as quite a dry industry, whilst reflecting our professionalism and attention to detail

Or should it be more specific, i.e. something that can be measured?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of measurable information you would be able to bring to bear on a new brand identity.  Granted, you would want to make sure that appropriate research in terms of marketplace saturation, etc. had been done, but until the brand (and company) has been in the marketplace, I am not sure that there is much beyond the more general information that you have shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing from scratch the main priority, is defining the identity of the brand, and this is an accumulated understanding of the business from, It's goal, vision, mission statement, value proposition, target audience, market niche, and peculiarities that birthed the idea in the first place. Aside asking questions that relate to aesthetics and visual concepts, a good brand or logo design project should be able to distill all that information into a recognizable item that accurately and succinctly communicates the brand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question. You are not providing enough info as to why you need to come back to this.

When a business owner invests in marketing, what he eventually seeks is to boost sales, profit, company value, etc. This is the general purpose of marketing as a broad term. And yes marketing includes everything, branding, rebranding, website, brochure, pens with logos and planes with logos, you name it.

Even your example uses the term "stand out" which ultimately means getting more business. He doesn't want to show off his one of a kind logo. He wants to reach into his competitors' client base.

Comment: thanks for your input... as for me needing to come back to it, it's a different question to my last one. As stated in one of the answers I received to my other question,  a rebrand is entirely different to designing a brand from scratch