# How to respond to Brand identity Objections from small business owners?

Tags: client-relations, presentation

When pitching a client on a brand identity service and they ask you,"how do I know this will work?" What would be the appropriate response?

Comment: [Related question+answers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/110017/120647)

Comment: @Danielillo That question and answers don't seem very related to me.

Comment: That's why I didn't put it as a dup. The title is quite similar (Brand identity Objections), not the question content: how do I know this will work?

Comment: Related Question: [What kind of goals would come out of a rebrand?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91056/what-kind-of-goals-would-come-out-of-a-rebrand)

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer right now but...marketing research, focus groups...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I know this will work?

This is **entirely** based upon the client and the work being created. There's no "solid" or "universal" reply without some direct knowledge of what was created, what the client was seeking, and the target audience.

Some *very broad* responses......

- Well, there are no guarantees with anything conceptual in nature. I can merely pull on my experience and try to target what I know appeals to your audience. Such as X, Y, Z.
- It's been my experiences that X leads to higher retention and memorability by viewers.
- Studies have shown that the color X promotes a sense of X in viewers
- By using a serif/sans serif typeface such as [typeface] it offers a more friendly/informational impression.
- If you examine brands from your competitors you can see they use a great deal of X. I've used that in a similar fashion [here] in order to promote a sense of "belonging" in the overall industry.

Answer (score 6):

We can't know if this will work. What we can know is that you don't feel your current brand isn't working for reasons A, B, and C. We've addressed those issues through X, Y, and Z.

If you can't frame it in this way than the rebrand either wasn't needed or wasn't well scoped to begin with. In that case you really are just guessing with the money of a small business owner that may not be able to afford an expensive rebrand that doesn't improve anything.

For more on why to rebrand to begin with see [What kind of goals would come out of a rebrand?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91056/what-kind-of-goals-would-come-out-of-a-rebrand)